# How can i implement this class for new class in Activity?

Tags: android

**PostData**

```
public class PostData {
    @Expose
    private String text;
    @Expose
    private Point point;
    public class Point implements Serializable {
        @Expose
        private double longitude;
        @Expose
        private double latitude;
        public Point(double longitude, double latitude) {
            this.longitude = longitude;
            this.latitude = latitude;
        }
    }
    public PostData(String text, Point point) {
        this.text = text;
        this.point = point;
    }
}
```

I want use it like

`PostData postData = new PostData()`

so i tried this like

```
   PostData postData = new PostData("nqq", mpoint){
                  Point mpoint = new PostData.Point("13", "14");
                };
```

But it has something wrong.

Actually i don't know how to deal with `point` class.

Would you let me know example?

How can i use it in right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using inner class , separate `PostData` and `Point` Class

```
   public class PostData {
        @Expose
        private String text;
        @Expose
        private Point point;

        public PostData(String text, Point point) {
            this.text = text;
            this.point = point;
        }
    }

    public class Point implements Serializable {
        @Expose
        private double longitude;
        @Expose
        private double latitude;
        public Point(double longitude, double latitude) {
            this.longitude = longitude;
            this.latitude = latitude;
        }
    }
```

And then use like this way

```
Point point = new Point(13,14);
PostData postData = new PostData("nqq",point);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but from your vague question I suppose you have problem initializing your point class object and passing it in your PostData class constructor.if yes? then this should work.

```
PostData.Point mpoint = new PostData.Point("13", "14");     
PostData postData = new PostData("nqq", mpoint);
```

Comment: Thanks for advice farhan patel